# setting property of a proxy object failed, had to get the actual object

Tags: php, symfony

I have a code like this and it did not work:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$accountObj->setHasCheckpoint(1);
$em->flush();
```

and I had to do the following:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findOneById($accountObj->getId());
$user->setHasCheckpoint(1);
$em->flush();
```

in order to get has checkpoint to be set. Why is this?
accountObj was just another `$entity->getUser();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set Doctrine2 entity property without retrieving entire associated object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007843/set-doctrine2-entity-property-without-retrieving-entire-associated-object)

Answer (score 0):

Because `$accountObj` is not managed (or *watched*) by the entity manger when the `flush` method is called, unlike `$user` which is fetched directly from `$em`.

If you want to update `$accountObj` without fetching another instance, you should tell the entity manager to manage the `$accountObj` object before calling `flush`:

```
$em->persist($accountObj);
$em->flush();
```